# LUA io.read() statement makes output blank

Tags: input, lua, console, output

If I put io.read() anywhere in my program nothing is outputted at all in the console even if I have like a print statement somewhere else, but things like io.write() work. I've got no clue how to fix it.

(using Sublime Text 3)

I have installed these packages (if it makes any difference):
- Lua Dev
- Package Control
- Sidebar Enhancements
- SublimeLinter
- SublimeLinter-lua

Comment: Please post the actual exact code you're running.

Comment: io.read() reads, it does not write as the name suggests. why do you expect any output from it?

Comment: As said in previous comments, please provide actual code and expected output.